# what is the usage of -webkit-fill-available?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, material-ui, frontend, styles

PIC-1

this is what I've ( pic-1 )

[image: this is what I've ( pic-1 )]

PIC-2

this is what I need ( pic-2 )

[image: this is what I need ( pic-2 )]

in the pic-2 I added

```
width: -webkit-fill-available;
```

I got what I expect. But I don't know how it's working.

Answer (score 33):

So there are two things you need to know about this:

```
 -webkit-fill-available;
```

the -webkit part is an extension for browsers such as safari or chrome, you can find more examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions
This mean that this code will not work in firefox, to cover every browsers you could use something like that:

```
elem {
    width: 100%;
    width: -moz-available;          /* WebKit-based browsers will ignore this. */
    width: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Mozilla-based browsers will ignore this. */
    width: fill-available;
}
```

And the 'fill-available' part means the element will expand to take all available space in it's container. That's why your line stretched.

Hope I could clear it up for you.

Comment: thanks, Dendenzilla. I got cleared up now. will try what you suggested.

Comment: Glad I could help, if so please check the answer as a resolution to the problem so this topic can be closed. Have a nice day.

Comment: from what i can tell, `fill-available` is similar to `100%`, but won't cause an overflow if there are margins/padding/borders

Comment: Having a hard time finding documentation about `fill-available`. This thread is the most info I could find :(

Comment: @12Me21 So basically `fill-available` is `100%` with `box-sizing: border-box` ?

Comment: not exactly, because it also takes margins into account (as well as padding on the parent element)

Comment: Will this be a 'thing'? It's really good!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a more modern solution is to use `fit-content` instead.

See [MDN fit-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content) and [Can I Use fit-content](https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content)

Note that, at the time of this post, **Can I Use** states that Samsung Internet still requires `-webkit-fill-available` for `min-width`.

Comment: `fit-content` is different than `fill-available`. Try experimenting with `height: 100%` vs `fill-available` in a parent/child scenario, then throw in `fit-content` for comparison.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund Yes, `fit-content` is different to `fill-available`. However, I believe `fit-content` can be used to provide the OP, and others, with a better solution.  I don't believe it warranted a downvote.