# safe-area-inset works in embedded browser but not in Safari

Tags: css, ios, capacitor, safearea

I'm working on a [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) project. While running my app on an iPhone 13 [XCode simulator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-your-app-in-the-simulator-or-on-a-device) I noticed that `env(safe-area-inset-bottom)` works as expected in the app's internal browser ([Capacitor is using a WebView under the hood](https://ionicframework.com/docs/core-concepts/webview)). However, if I open the app directly as a website in Safari or Chrome, the same property doesn't seem to work.

Here's my sample CSS:

```
.footer {
  padding: 16px 16px env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
}
```

And my logic (the used JavaScript library is irrelevant):

```
<div class="footer">
  FOOTER: {getComputedStyle(footer).padding}
</div>
```

And here's my `viewport` meta tag that [should enable the usage of env() variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env#usage):

```
<meta
  name="viewport"
  content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
/>
```

And here's a screenshot from the Capacitor app:

[image]

And from Safari:

[image]

What is the reason for this inconsistency and what am I missing?

Comment: Could you take a loot at: 
https://www.angularfix.com/2022/08/safe-area-inset-bottom-not-working-on.html
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68270606

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately that didn't help 